# Cache index.html on service worker install when serving from subpath

Tags: javascript, url, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

It's me again, messing with service workers...

This time my question has to do with precaching assets, to wit `index.html`, when serving the PWA from a subpath on the server, not root. So, I can't cache `/` on `cache.addAll()` as that is considered an absolute path, not relative to the scope.

The reason why I have to do this is that I'm going to serve my PWA from GitHub Pages, and that means it will be served from a subpath on my GitHub Pages domain, not root. So, I've not specified any `scope` property on the `manifest.json`, to get a default one.

I'm not hardcoding the subpath to be able to serve the PWA from GitHub Pages and from a local server when developing at home, because for reasons too long to explain here, the PWA has to work when both served from the root of a domain and an arbitrary subfolder.

My two options right now are the following:

```
// This works perfectly, but I don't feel comfortable using the scope by hand...
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(staticCache).then(cache => {
            return cache.addAll([
                new URL(self.registration.scope).pathname,
                'index.html',
                'index.css',
                'index.js',
                'manifest.json',
                'appicon.png',
                'favicon.ico',
          ]);
        })
    );
});
```

```
// This works too, but I don't know if this may fail in some servers
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(staticCache).then(cache => {
            return cache.addAll([
                '.',
                'index.html',
                'index.css',
                'index.js',
                'manifest.json',
                'appicon.png',
                'favicon.ico',
          ]);
        })
    );
});
```

**Which one is the best practice? Will something fail with the second one?**

**Thanks** in advance and sorry for my weird questions, but I'm trying to learn and this corner cases are not frequent so I'm not finding much information.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a best practice on this? I'm surprised this isn't something better documented.

Comment: Nope @SJML, I'm sorry but as you say, it's not very well documented (or I'm unable to find the relevant documentation). I'm using the second solution for now because it's what I've seen more frequently and it seems to work OK, so...